# display 2nd set of radio button when the value of 1st set of radio button is checked

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

What I want is, when I checked the first set of radio button (name = source; value from database), they can show the second set of radio button (name = exam; the value also from database)

```
<?php 

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM source'; 
$query = mysql_query($sql); 

while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo '<input type="radio" name="source" value="'.$row['s_id'].'">'.$row['s_desc']; 
   }

*if ($source.checked){
echo '<input type="radio" name="exam" value="'.$row['e_id'].'">'.$row['e_desc']; 
   }
}*
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$source is not defined in this extract. Do you mean $row['checked']?

Perhaps it would help to check that the values returned by the query are in fact the values that you expect to see. If you use the following lines, it will temporarily break your layout, but it will help you confirm that your query is functioning as expected.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo '<input type="radio" name="source" value="'.$row['s_id'].'">'.$row['s_desc'];

  echo '<br />checked: '.$row['checked'];
  echo '<br />e_id: '.$row['e_id'];
  echo '<br />e_desc: '.$row['e_desc'];
  }
```

Where are you "checking" the state of rb1? My current guess is that the end user will be checking a radio button in an HTML page served by your PHP script... but you are looking in a database on the server for information on the locally checked state of the button. If my guess is right, you don't want to serve the page again after each click. Instead you can serve the page with all the possible buttons, and use CSS to hide the rb2 buttons whose rb1 button is not selected.

CAUTION: UNTESTED PHP

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo '<input type="radio" name="source" value="'.$row['s_id'].'"';
  echo 'onclick=yourJavaScriptFunctionToDisplayTheRB2Button()';
  echo '>'.$row['s_desc'];

  echo '<input type="radio" name="exam" value="'.$row['e_id'].'"';
  if (!$row['checked']) {
    echo ' style="visibility=hidden"';
  }
  echo '>'.$row['e_desc'];
  }
```

For yourJavaScriptFunctionToDisplayTheRB2Button(), see the jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c62dJ/1/).

Comment: yup... but i've no idea how to show the 2nd radio button based on the 1st radio button... because both of them from database...

Comment: thanx mr. james newton, i follow your suggestion but it effect's nothing... perhap i must explain detail about my problem.. i have 2 tables contain the value of the 2 sets of radio button... table1 contain s_id, s_desc (display as rb1) and table2 contain e_id,e_desc, s_id.. (display as rb2)... both of them successfull display when i select it from tables... the situation is, i want to show rb2 after i checked rb1 according to s_id... i hope i gave a clear explanation... i really appreciate your help... tq